# How to drag around a SKSpriteNode using Pin Joints

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to be able to pick up a SKSpriteNode and in effect "dangle" it with my finger. I've been experimenting with SKPhysicsJointPin but it doesn't seem to be delivering the desired result.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if !BeingMoved {
                BeingMoved = true
                TempDragNode.name = "TempDragNode"
                TempDragNode.size = CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)
                TempDragNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 44)

                TempDragNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                addChild(TempDragNode)

                TempDragNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

                let PositionX = CGPoint(x: TempDragNode.position.x, y: TempDragNode.position.y+(TempDragNode.frame.height/2))

                let PinJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: (childNode(withName: "Nutty")?.physicsBody)!, bodyB: TempDragNode.physicsBody!, anchor: PositionX)

                scene?.physicsWorld.add(PinJoint)


            }

            TempDragNode.position = location
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what this does compared to what you want it to?

Comment: Why are you redefining the physics body and its joints in touchesMoved? Surely any 'inertia' being applied from the movement will be removed as the physics body and the joint are deleted and redefined. Is the dragging working but without any 'dangle' effect?

Comment: Hi there. I'm doing this from touches moved because I want this to only begin once the user starts dragging. And as you'll notice there's a "BeingMoved" Boolean that prevents it from being repeated.

Comment: Currently, this is what it does: https://imgur.com/a/ekiju63

Comment: Hmmm - what happens if you try to drag it slowly, so that the 'touch' is always within the red square? IT appears that if the touch moves outside of the red square, you drop it, but then half-way through it appears as though the blue square becomes anchored in place and the red square is trying to move but is somehow constrained within a certain distance of the blue square.

Comment: I think the red square's 'jittering' is because you are setting it's position directly, but because of the physicsJointPin, it gets pulled back to the blue square. Is there anything in your code that prevents the blue square from moving after some event etc?

Comment: What I shared is literally the only code in the app. (Aside from essential things like the view controller's setup for the SKView & the required stuff in the Scene controller).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182966/discussion-between-steve-ives-and-user10194586).

Comment: Bump. As this still hasn’t been solved...